# GoogleAds API Test Account setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

Before trying with the production data, I'm going to try using the Google Ads API with a test account.  I have already set up that and I have the `Customer ID`, `manager account customer ID`, and the `developer token`.  The next step in the docs states I need to set up the .yaml file which has the follwing fields:

```
developer_token: INSERT_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE
client_id: INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID_HERE
client_secret: INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE
refresh_token: INSERT_REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE
login_customer_id: INSERT_LOGIN_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE
```

My question here is what is the `client_id` and `client_secret`?
I know that the `refresh_token` needs to set up like this in their docs:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/oauth-installed

Is the `client_id` and `secret_id` the `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` setup in the my personal account in the developer console?

*I am using the Google Ads API and NOT the AdWords API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the GoogleAds Team and they confirmed that the client_id and client_secret are from the email account that has access to specified Test Account/Campaigns.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not true. You can setup OAuth2 clients with a Google account that has no access to Google Ads and still use them to create a refresh token with another Google account that does have access.

Comment: right, you can populate the refresh token even though you don't have access, but you will need to have access to the campaign if you want to have permission to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you were able to successfully perform an OAuth2 authorization flow with the required scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords` in order to obtain your refresh token.

The OAuth2 client ID and secret values that you set in `googleads`'s configuration file are the exact same ones you used for the auth flow. I assume that's what you refer to as being setup in you personal account in the developer console.